# Javascript new operator *always* overrides return value?

Tags: javascript

Based on these specs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) about how the new operator works:

> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of
>   the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>   explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>   instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>   choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>   process.)

I am lead to believe that the new operator only overrides the return value if one hasn't been provided. Yet it seems that it always does so and you can *never* override it.

For example

```
function test() { return 1; }
new test() // returns {} and not 1
```

Can someone give an example where this is not the case, such as they are referring to in the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwite the result only with a non primitive value.

With primitive

```js
function test() { this.bar = '42'; return 1; }
console.log(new test()) // {}
```

With object, without primitive

```js
function test() { this.bar = '42'; return { foo: 'bar' }; }
console.log(new test()) //  { foo: 'bar' };
```

With array, without primitive

```js
function test() { this.bar = '42'; return [42]; }
console.log(new test()) // [42];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition [@nina-scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020511/4791116) answer we can use a `new` primitive object and a function to get access to primitive value from the function invoked with `new` operator

**With appropriate `new` primitive object**

```js
function test() {
  this.bar = '42';
  return new Number(1);
}
const num = new test()

console.log(num.valueOf()) // 1
console.log(num + 0) // 1
```

**With function** as a work around, without primitive

```js
function test() {
  this.bar = '42';
  return () => { return 1 };
}

console.log(new test()()) // 1
```